# Apple iPhone 5 doesn't charge attached to a laptop

Tags: iphone, charging

My Apple iPhone 5 doesn't charge attached to a laptop. It works fine attached to a wall charger. Plugging in the USB cable into laptop doesn't generate an audible feedback. I am running Windows 8.1 Professional.

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: does this port on your laptop work when you plug other things into it (like a mouse or keyboard)?

Answer (score 1):

This can have 2 reasons
1. You're using an aftermarket cable with too much electrical loss.
2. Your laptop USB port(s) don't deliver enough power.

Both situations sometimes are paired with the iPhone making non stop charge-beeps like you connect and disconnect the charging cable - but I read that this is not the case with you.

I found out that this situation comes up less frequently, once the iPhone battery is above 70 or so percent.

Comment: I also used genuine data cable but nothing happened, And my iphone 4 charge perfect fine with my laptop. I also check my iphone 5 to connect with other laptop but the result is same,  And when i connect my iphone 5 with any laptop there is no charge beep or connecting beep originates from either phone or the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it did charge once on my laptop but it didn't again after that... The percentage on my phone was 39% when it worked but it charged up to 70 odd percent, So I'm thinking that it doesn't charge past 70 odd percent... I only really need it to charge because I'm trying to get files onto and off my phone but I can't do that, so I need to wait till its at about 10 - 20% before I can do that.
Hope this helped :)